# Groupby, Split, and Count Combinations (removing loop for pytorch performance)

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, gpu

I am attempting to increase the performance of the following snippet of code for execution on the GPU:

```
[torch.combinations(doc_ids, r=2) for doc_ids in torch.split(X, C)]
```

It would be wonderful to remove the loops here for something more amenable to the GPU.  I wanted to see if anyone has any suggestions towards this end.

I know something is going quite wrong here, because the GPU benchmarking is far slower than the same code on CPU.

Ultimately, the problem statement I am working on would be something like "given a matrix X with shape n_docs x m_features, count the number of shared features between docs".

The actual code I have for this is slightly more complex (some concatenation and sorting in the snippet - see below), but it appears that this inclusion of `for` and `torch.combinations` has really tanked the performance.

Here is a small bit of code to reproduce an aspect of what I am doing, along with some benchmarking:

```
import torch
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import perfplot

# Dummy Data
############


def load_data(n_docs=100000,
              doc_id_start=13340,
              max_feats_per_doc=20):
    # Document IDs each have an undetermined number of features
    doc_range = np.arange(doc_id_start, n_docs+doc_id_start)
    doc_ids = np.concatenate([[docid]*np.random.randint(max_feats_per_doc)
                              for docid in doc_range]).ravel()

    feature_ids = np.random.randint(100000, 900000, size=len(doc_ids))

    # DataFrame of starting data (Doc_id, feature_id)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.stack([doc_ids, feature_ids]).T,
                      columns=["doc_id", "feature_id"])

    # Every `int_rate` number of documents, look to pair some features with
    # another document
    int_rate = 27
    # Approximate percentage of features that may be shared
    prob_share = 0.2
    for doc_ix, (doc_id, gdf) in enumerate(df.groupby("doc_id")):
        if doc_ix % int_rate == 0:
            this_ix = gdf.index #df[df.doc_id == doc_id].index
            # Random other document
            other_doc = np.random.choice(doc_ids)
            other_features = df[df.doc_id == other_doc].feature_id
            # Insert a few items from the other document
            new_features = [f if prob_share < np.random.rand()
                              else np.random.choice(other_features)
                            for f in gdf.feature_id]
            df.loc[this_ix, "feature_id"] = new_features

    print("Initial Dataframe of (Doc_id, feature_id) data:")
    print(df)
    print(df.feature_id.value_counts())
    return df


# Groupby feature and count shared docs
#######################################

def gpu_groupby_features(frame,
                         min_collisions=2,
                         max_collisions=40,
                         force_cpu=False,
                         do_combs=True):
    torch.autograd.set_grad_enabled(False)
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available()
                          and not force_cpu else "cpu")

    # Detach from computational graph (this isn't a NN)
    X = torch.from_numpy(frame.values).to(device).detach()

    # Removing the rows which do not have a duplicated feature_id
    #   *really* improves the speed (~20x) (less iterations in the for loop)
    U, I, C = torch.unique(X[:, 1], return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
    # Number of docs sharing each feature
    D = C.gather(index=I, dim=0)
    # Good row (doc_id-feature_id pair) boolean index
    B = (min_collisions <= D)# & (D <= max_collisions)

    # Filter to only the relevant (duplicated feature_id) data
    X = X[B]

    # Sort the (document_id, feature_id) pairs by the feature ids
    srt_ix = X[:, 1].argsort()
    X = X[srt_ix]

    ###############################################
    # Apparent Bottleneck
    ###############################################
    # Now that we have sorted X by feature_id, if we get the counts for each,
    #   this will give us a list of sizes to split the array
    U, C = torch.unique(X[:, 1], return_counts=True)
    C = list(C.cpu().numpy())
    if len(C)>0 and do_combs:
        doc_pairs = torch.cat(
                   [torch.combinations(doc_ids.unique(), r=2).sort()[0]
                    for doc_ids in torch.split(X[:, 0], split_size_or_sections=C)],
                   dim=0)

        # now count the document pairings
        U, C = torch.unique(doc_pairs, dim=0, return_counts=True)
        out = torch.cat([U, torch.unsqueeze(C, 1)], dim=1)
        srt_ix = out[:, 2].argsort()
        out = out[srt_ix]
        out = pd.DataFrame(out.cpu().numpy(),
                            columns=["docid_0", "docid_1", "count"])
        return out.sort_values(["count", "docid_0", "docid_1"])
    elif len(C)==0:
        print("No duplicates present")
        return
    else:
        return


def get_combs(x):
    min_collisions=2
    feat, doc_id_df = x
    if min_collisions <= len(doc_id_df):#& len(doc_id_df) <= max_collisions
        return [sorted(pair) for pair in
                itertools.combinations(set(doc_id_df.doc_id.tolist()), r=2)]
    else:
        return


def pandas_groupby_features(df,
                            min_collisions=2,
                            max_collisions=40):

    results = []
    with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as p:
        for docpair_list in p.imap(get_combs, df.groupby("feature_id")):
            if docpair_list:
                results += docpair_list

    results = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["docid_0", "docid_1"])
    results = results.value_counts(["docid_0", "docid_1"])
    results.name = "count"
    results = results.reset_index()
    return results.sort_values(["count", "docid_0", "docid_1"])


n_range = [10000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 1000000]
df = load_data(n_range[-1])
test1 = gpu_groupby_features(df[:n_range[-1]])
print(test1)
test2 = pandas_groupby_features(df[:n_range[-1]])
print(test2)
print(np.all(test1.values==test2.values))

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: df[:n],
    kernels=[
        lambda a: gpu_groupby_features(a),
        lambda a: gpu_groupby_features(a, do_combs=False),
        lambda a: gpu_groupby_features(a, force_cpu=True),
        lambda a: gpu_groupby_features(a, force_cpu=True, do_combs=False),
        lambda a: pandas_groupby_features(a)
    ],
    equality_check=None,
    labels=["GPU_torch", "GPU_torch_without_combos",
            "CPU_torch", "CPU_torch_without_combos",
            "pandas_multiprocessing"],
    n_range=n_range,
    max_time=120,
    xlabel="n_docs"
)
```

The output of this benchmarking code shows the following:

[image]

As you may notice, the GPU implementation is ***much slower*** than the CPU (pytorch) implementation.  I have included the `without_combos` for comparison to show that much of the processing time goes into the `torch.combinations` and `torch.split` part of the code.
The pandas implementation is also included as a reference point for a simplistic approach to the problem.

I have noticed that removing the feature_ids that are not duplicated first helps quite a bit with performance.  So, it's possible that separating the problem into groups of data that have the same number of doc_ids per feature_id may improve speed substantially, but I am not sure what the simplest method to do that would be.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found a large performance increase by iteratively filtering to only views of the array wherein a certain feature is shared by *n* number of docs.  In doing so (along with sorting by the features), you can use the slice syntax which skips every *n* rows.
Then the combinations can be achieved by slicing to the combinatorial indices - but now it gathers the entire array at once, rather than looping through each group.

The text above may not make any sense, so here's the function I ended up using:

```
def doc_pairs_with_n_docs_per_shingle(X, nps=2):
    U, I, C = torch.unique(X[:, 1],
                           return_counts = True,
                           return_inverse = True)
    # Filter array by number of documents shared by each feature
    #   nps is the *desired* number of documents shared by each feature
    D = C.gather(index=I, dim=0)
    B = D == nps

    X = X[B]
    X = X[X[:, 1].argsort()]
    ixs = list(itertools.combinations(range(nps), r=2))
    doc_pairs = torch.vstack([torch.column_stack(
                                (X[ix[0]::nps, 0],
                                 X[ix[1]::nps, 0])).sort(axis=1)[0]
                              for ix in ixs])
    return doc_pairs

def gpu_doc_pairs(frame,
                  min_collisions=2,
                  max_collisions=40,
                  force_cpu=False,
                  do_combs=True):
    torch.autograd.set_grad_enabled(False)
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available()
                          and not force_cpu else "cpu")

    # Detach from computational graph (this isn't a NN)
    X = torch.from_numpy(frame.values).to(device).detach()

    # Removing the rows which do not have a duplicated feature_id
    #   *really* improves the speed (~20x) (less iterations in the for loop)
    U, I, C = torch.unique(X[:, 1], return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
    # Number of docs sharing each feature
    D = C.gather(index=I, dim=0)
    # Good row (doc_id-feature_id pair) boolean index
    B = (min_collisions <= D)# & (D <= max_collisions)

    # Filter to only the relevant (duplicated feature_id) data
    X = X[B]

    # Sort the (document_id, feature_id) pairs by the feature ids
    srt_ix = X[:, 1].argsort()
    X = X[srt_ix]

    results = []
    for n_docs_per_feature in range(min_collisions):#, max_collisions):
        doc_pairs = doc_pairs_with_n_docs_per_shingle(X,
                                                      nps=n_docs_per_feature)
        if len(doc_pairs)>0:
            # Now count the document pairings
            U, C = torch.unique(doc_pairs, dim=0, return_counts=True)
            C = torch.unsqueeze(C, 1)
            arr = torch.cat([U, C], dim=1)
            srt_ix = arr[:, 2].argsort()
            arr = arr[srt_ix]
            results += [arr.cpu().numpy()]

    results = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(results),
                        columns=["docid_0", "docid_1", "count"])
    return results.sort_values(["count", "docid_0", "docid_1"])
```

In order to achieve this performance (GPU_group_approach):

[image]

And zoomed in:

[image]

I know this is ugly at the moment. Hopefully I can clean it up and make it more generalized (a `torch.groupby` type of function would be nice for example), but for now if anyone hits a similar problem they may find some insight in this.

Comment: Note that finding unique values is a computation that is hard to do efficiently on GPUs as opposed to on CPUs (especially when done using multiple threads). Even state of the art algorithm are not so good. Still, if your GPU is a high-end one and you CPU is not very powerful too, the GPU implementation can be faster (though it should consume significantly more energy).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for the comment, I will keep that in mind.  I was really hopeful to get this working on GPU for a speedup, but you may be right.  Perhaps I will benchmark the pytorch CPU version of the same algorithm and compare.  I suppose that if the CPU version consistently outperforms the GPU version here, I could simply remove the pytorch dependency altogether for multiprocessing, as nvidia continually is ruining everything (tf, pytorch, essentially all python dev) with breaking changes with every update.